# Angular: Asynchronous Promise in Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {

    $scope.pageData = {};


    myService.promiseGetDataFromServer()
        .then(function (response) {
        $scope.pageData = response.data;

    }, function (reason) {
       // error has occurred.. etc...
    });
}
```

Up to this point everything work fine. However, I would like to populate `$scope.pageData` based off of some deterministic logic. I tried this:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService2, thing) {

   $scope.pageData = {}

   switch (thing)
   {
       case 'whatever':
         myService2.promiseGetWhateverFromServer()
            .then(function (response) {
            $scope.pageData = response.data;

         }, function (reason) {
           // error has occurred.. etc...
         });
        break;

        case 'something':

          myService2.promiseGetSomethingFromServer()
              .then(function (response) {
              $scope.pageData = response.data;

           }, function (reason) {
              // error has occurred.. etc...
           });
           break;
   }

}
```

There were no server errors, and I logged the response and everything was good, but my view did not render since I suspect the properties of `$scope.pageData` were undefined.

How do I get around this? I want the view to load after that switch statement has resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I ma getting you right you could separate the logic with selecting approproate sevice and doing the request, like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService2, thing) {

   $scope.pageData = {};

  //here we select service
  $scope.getDataForPageData = function(parameter){
    var serviceToSelect;

     switch (parameter)
     {
         case 'whatever':
           serviceToSelect = myService1;
          break;

          case 'another'
          serviceToSelect = myService2;
          break;
     }

     return serviceToSelect;

  }

  //do request and assign $scope.pageData when resolved
  $scope.getDataForPageData(thing).promiseGetSomethingFromServer()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.pageData = response.data;

        }, function (reason) {
           // error has occurred.. etc...
        });

}
```